# Problem with POST verb in ocelot api gateway implementation

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, api-gateway, ocelot

Here is my ocelot.json, when I hit GET *https://localhost:44368/WeatherForecast* it works fine. But when I post a user Login request with POST *https://localhost:44368/Login* it returns a 404 error. What I actually miss I can't find it out. But when I use a direct URL then it works.
[swagger_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqQOS.png)

```
Console Log
Error Code: UnableToFindDownstreamRouteError Message: Failed to match Route configuration for upstream path: /Login, verb: POST
```

```
ocelot.json file
{
  "Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api​/WeatherForecast​/Get",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": "44385"
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/WeatherForecast",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [
        "GET"
      ]
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api​/Auth​/Login",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": "44320"
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/Login",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [
        "POST"
      ]

    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you change your code with ````"UpstreamPathTemplate": "/Login"````

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but still not working, return 404 @OnurkanBakırcı

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem, that is there is two ocelot.json files based on the environment variable,

- ocelot.json
- ocelot.development.json

I added the downstream mapping on ocelot.json file, but my settings was

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            webBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
            config.AddJsonFile($"ocelot.{env}.json"));
        });
```

it always finds the ocelot.development.json where I didn't put the downstream mapping for */Login*